# Any other way to detect click outside?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, click, dom-events

The common method is to attach a click event listener on `body` and check `if e.target` is your element, or if `e.target` contains your element.

This is fine and it works, but i was wondering if there some other way to do this that does not require attaching events on some other element outside your target, like body?

My use case is a select box component for vuejs. It doesn't feel right to attach click listener on bodies for each select box component.

Comment: Not really. If the idea is to listen for clicks on an outer container, which are not on an inner container, you can't really avoid adding a listener to an outer container

Comment: [This module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-click-outside) looks good and probably worth a try.

Comment: @YomS. That still does [exactly the same thing though](https://github.com/vue-bulma/click-outside/blob/master/index.js#L56)

Comment: ok, then are there some performance improvements I can add in that listener before calling element.contains? I think that it's expensive to run that on every click.

Comment: You can attach a single listener that will handle multiple boxes though I'm not sure it's worth it. Don't run element.contains check when clicks don't need to be detected, e.g. select box is closed.